# Get SharePoint 2010 log path

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Please provide me code to get SharePoint 2010 log path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spdiagnosticsservice.loglocation.aspx

```
SPDiagnosticsService.Local.LogLocation
```